# automatic updates of Nvidia, Cuda under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, updates, cuda

I have two Nvidia GPUs (RTX 2060 and RTX 2080 Ti) I use with TensorFlow 2 (installed in a Python virtualenv). I have installed CUDA 10.1 (which is not the latest version) as required by the installation instructions (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu). The installation process was painful, but the GPUs work now. I regularly get many requests of update concerning Nvidia/CUDA from Ubuntu Software Updater, but I am not sure whether this will cause an update of the version of CUDA, which I do not want.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening (while still installing the right updates)?